# how does CVE-2015-5207 and CVE-2015-5208 work and could be triggered?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-ios

just like what the title says

I couldn't find a single detailed explanation with this vulnerabilities

any comments is appreciated

see link for more info
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2016/04/27/security.html

Answer (score 1):

The NVD is a product of the NIST Computer Security Division and is sponsored by the Department of Homeland Security's National Cyber Security Division. This is the official resource to see more information about announced vulnerabilities:

https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-5207
https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-5208

You could investigate this further by analyzing the Cordova iOS source on GitHub and history of commits:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios

The CVE sometimes is not incredibly descriptive on how the bug actually works because they're trying to thwart less-skilled hackers from easily writing exploits for the bug immediately after it's released. Oftentimes you will have to investigate the source code to see what changes were made yourself to recreate the problem.

Comment: i tried checking the commit history and there wasnt any trace that i could find the exact changes related to the CVE issue

but anyway thanks for the help